# Equal span heights in twitter bootstrap framework

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to do a lot of research on getting equal height spans especially for bootstrap. I came across the plugin by filament group but I have no clue why it's not working as expected.
Reference to http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chou_one/vbAD6/10/) I would like to have all the spans to be of equal height. I have called the `equalHeights()` method plugin correctly but no luck.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1):

your code is not working because you have not included equal height plugin.
If you do not have to use the plugin try this code

```
 $(function() {
   var maxHeight=0;
   $('.span4').each(function(){
      if($(this).height()>maxHeight) {
       maxHeight=$(this).height();
      }
   });

    $('.span4').height(maxHeight);
});
```

check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgCQK/)

** note : your element id should be unique, check in fiddle i have done.

Comment: Thanks...but what if I want to use this code for different spans.. like for span6, span2  and span4? I think this code should be fine if the plugin is not working effectively. Although, do I need to enter any parameters? e.g..I just use this $('.span4').equalHeights();

Comment: oh ok I got it...we use one span as the main row to compare and then make the other ones to match that height.. i have fixed the fiddle..thanks a lot for your code...really helpful!